# Converting EF Core queries from 2.2 to 3.0 - async await

Tags: c#, entity-framework, async-await, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

In EF Core 2.2 I had:

```
      var data = await _ArticleTranslationRepository.DbSet
        .Include(arttrans => arttrans.Article)
        .ThenInclude(art => art.Category)
        .Where(trans => trans.Article != null && trans.Article.Category != null && trans.Article.Category.Id == categoryId.Value)
        .GroupBy(trans => trans.ArticleId)
        .Select(g => new { ArticleId = g.Key, TransInPreferredLang = g.OrderByDescending(trans => trans.LanguageId == lang).ThenByDescending(trans => trans.LanguageId == defaultSiteLanguage).ThenBy(trans => trans.LanguageId).FirstOrDefault() })
        .Select(at => at.TransInPreferredLang)
        .OrderBy(at => at.Article.SortIndex)
        .ToListAsync();
```

Now with EF Core 3.0 I had to write:

```
      var data = _ArticleTranslationRepository.DbSet
  .Include(arttrans => arttrans.Article)
  .ThenInclude(art => art.Category)
  .Where(trans => trans.Article != null && trans.Article.Category != null && trans.Article.Category.Id == categoryId.Value)
    .AsEnumerable() // client side groupby is not supported (.net core 3.0 (18 nov. 2019)
  .GroupBy(trans => trans.ArticleId)
  .Select(g => new { ArticleId = g.Key, TransInPreferredLang = g.OrderByDescending(trans => trans.LanguageId == lang).ThenByDescending(trans => trans.LanguageId == defaultSiteLanguage).ThenBy(trans => trans.LanguageId).FirstOrDefault() })
  .Select(at => at.TransInPreferredLang)
  .OrderBy(at => at.Article.SortIndex)
  .ToList();
```

My asp.net core mvc actionmethod is async (`public virtual async Task<ICollection<…>>…`)
Because I used .AsEnumerable to force client side evaluation I also had to change `.ToListAsync()` to `.ToList()` and remove the `await` operator.

The query is working but produces a warning:
`This async method lacs 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await operator ….`

How can this EF Core 3.0 query be rewritten so that it uses async / await. I can't figure out how to include the `AsAsyncEnumerable()` in a **single** query/linq expression.

(I know that I can split it up in a 'server' part and a 'client-side' part, but I would like to see it in a single **async** linq expression as I had before in EF Core 2.2.)

Comment: Why did you need to force client-side evaluation? Instead of `AsEnumerable` use `ToListAsync` and store the result of that in a variable, then do the rest of the query on that.

Comment: because of " client side groupby is not supported" when using .GroupBy

Comment: [LINQ queries are no longer evaluated on the client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client) : _"Mitigations

If a query can't be fully translated, then either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or use AsEnumerable(), ToList(), or similar to explicitly bring data back to the client where it can then be further processed using LINQ-to-Objects."_

Comment: @Fildor: I have rewritten it, it works I'm using Asenumerable(). but it doesn't use async await anymore now. I can split it up indeed in a server side part and client side part but I'm wondering if I can write it async in a single linq "expression" using for example AsAsyncEnumerable.

Comment: Ah, I missed the point. Yes, I agree, I don't see how that could be done without tearing it into two pieces.

Comment: because I can't to `await ....ToListAsync().GroupBy(…` I know I have to separate it in two blocks. It is just some "syntactical sugar" I'm searching for.

Comment: You can do `(await /* ... */.ToListAsync()).GroupBy( /* ... */` - ie wrap the database-executed half in parentheses, awaiting it and then continue the chain on the result of the await - to do it in a single statement.

Comment: @Jesper I would rather do it on 2 lines for clarity. Using parens to do the await looks horribly messy, and hides the fact it's 2 distinct blocks unless you look carefully.

Comment: That's fair - you said you were looking for syntactical sugar, so I thought this was what you meant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The idea seems to be combining the `AsAsyncEnumerable()` with [System.Linq.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async) package which provides equivalent LINQ (`IEnumerable<T>`) extension methods for `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`.

So by idea if you install (or package reference) that package, inserting `.AsAsyncEnumerable()` before `.GroupBy`, the original query in question should work.

There is an annoying issue though with EF Core 3.0 `DbSet<T>` class. Since it implements both `IQueryable<T>` and `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` interfaces, and none of them is "better" (closer) match, many queries using standard LINQ operators on `DbSet<T>` will simply break at compile time with `CS0121` (ambiguous call) and will require adding `.AsQueryable()`. Queries which use EF Core specific extensions like `Include` / `ThenInclude` will work because they already resolve to `IQueryable<T>`.

As some people mentioned in the comments, it's possible to use `(await [serverPart...].ToListAsync())[clientPart...]` which eliminates the need of `System.Linq.Async` and associated compile time method ambiguity, but it has the same drawback as using `ToList()` instead of `AsEnumerable()` in the synchronous scenario by creating an unnecessary in-memory list.

---

Of course the best would be to avoid client evaluation at all by finding equivalent, but fully translatable LINQ construct. Which currently with `GroupBy` is hard, and sometimes even impossible. And even it is possible, it requires rewriting the previous query by eliminating the `GroupBy`. For instance, instead of starting the query from `ArticleTranslation` and grouping by `ArticleId`, you might start the query from `Article` and use the `Translations` collection navigation property with `OrderByDescending()...FirstOrDefault()` which is supported. Repeat the procedure for each failing query. The benefit will be that now your queries will execute server side as they should in the first place.

Comment: Why not using right tool for the job, EF Core LINQ translated to sql for simple queries and raw sql for `GroupBy` queries ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with dotnet core 5.0 and 6.0 and I solved it like this:

Install the nuget package System.Linq.Async depending of you dotnet version https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async

and then in your query you would be able to add the .ToAsyncEnumerable()

This a example:

```
        public async Task<IEnumerable<ProductTableView>> GetProduct(Pagination pagination, string identifier)
    {

        var ListProductsTable = await _context.ModelView
                                       .FromSqlRaw("GetProductByIdentifier {0}", identifier)
                                       .ToAsyncEnumerable()
                                       .Select(a => new ProductTableView
                                       {
                                           ID = a.ID,
                                           Guid = a.Guid,
                                           Guid_Product_Category = a.Guid_Product_Category,
                                           Guid_Currency = a.Guid_Currency,
                                           NameProduct = a.NameProduct,
                                       }).ToListAsync();

        return ListProductsTable;
    }
```

Comment: If you are using EF Core, then `ToAsyncEnumerable()` is already in the package: `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`.  You don't need to *separately* install: `System.Linq.Async`.