# ASP Net Core Web API: Client side GroupBy is not supported

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0, ef-core-3.1

I am new here, and a newbie in asp.net core.

I am writing a web api using asp.net core 3.0. I wrote the following API endpoint code to retrieve a list of `Databases` entities and group them by a field named `Value` from another object `Type`.

```cs
//GET:api/Databases/graph
[HttpGet("graph")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Database>>>> GetGraphDatabases()
{
    return await _context.Databases
        .Include(t => t.Type)
        .Where(d => d.Type.Code == "DATABASE_TYPE")
        .GroupBy(d => d.Type.Value)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

But when I try to reach the endpoint, I get the following error message: **InvalidOperationException: Client side GroupBy is not supported.**

I checked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58138556/client-side-groupby-is-not-supported) but it didn't help much.

Can you please support.

Comment: The question has been answered in the linked article. Which part of it you didn't understand or didn't help you? EF Core 3.x don't support server-sided grouping (yet...), that's the answer. Asking the same question again isn't going to change the answer: It's not supported. Group client sided or run a raw query or just wait until EF Core implements it

Comment: @Tseng you probably meant client side

Comment: No, client-sided (or client evaluation) is suppported and means fetching the ungroupd data and grouping in memory (via Linq-to-objects rather than Linq-to-sql). Server-sided grouping support means translating that expression into an SQL `GROUP BY` statement

Comment: Please upvote issue [#19929](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19929)

Answer (score 6):

Shortly, this type of `GroupBy` is not supported in EF Core 3.0.

You are expected to explicitly switch to client evaluation before that operator. Which for sync version is as simple as inserting `.AsEnumerable()`. For async version it's not that easy - there is `AsAsyncEnumerable()` method, but then you need additional package to get `GroupBy` and other LINQ operators available.

Probably the easiest way to resolve it (with the cost of one additional list in memory) is to use `ToListAsync()` to complete the async part and then use the regular LINQ to Objects for the rest.

e.g. something like this

```
return (await _context.Databases
    .Include(t => t.Type)
    .Where(d => d.Type.Code == "DATABASE_TYPE")
    .ToListAsync())
    .GroupBy(d => d.Type.Value);
```

---

The additional package I'm talking about is [System.Linq.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async). For more info, see [Converting EF Core queries from 2.2 to 3.0 - async await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58916542/converting-ef-core-queries-from-2-2-to-3-0-async-await/58920736#58920736).

Comment: thanks, would you mind tell me the other packages I will need.

Comment: Thank you, seems to work unfortunately the System.Linq.Async library create  conflicts in other part of my code.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that in the linked post, and not recommending it for now.