# No backing field could be found for property of entity type and the property does not have a getter

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am getting an exception

`System.InvalidOperationException : No backing field could be found for property 'ApartmentId' of entity type 'Address' and the property does not have a getter.`

This is my `Apartment` class:

```
public class Apartment
{
    public Apartment(Address address)
    {
        Address = address;
    }

    private Apartment()
    {
    }

    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public Address Address { get; private set; }
}
```

This is my `Address` value object class:

```
public class Address : IEquatable<Address>
{
    private Address()
    {
    }

    public Address(string streetNumber, string streetName, string city, string state, string zipCode)
    {
        StreetNumber = streetNumber;
        StreetName = streetName;
        City = city;
        State = state;
        ZipCode = zipCode;
    }

    public string StreetNumber { get; private set; }
    public string StreetName { get; private set; }
    public string City { get; private set; }
    public string State { get; private set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; private set; }

    public bool Equals(Address other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return String.Equals(StreetNumber, other.StreetNumber, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
               String.Equals(StreetName, other.StreetName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
               String.Equals(City, other.City, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
               String.Equals(State, other.State, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
               String.Equals(ZipCode, other.ZipCode, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

In my entity configuration I use `builder.OwnsOne(a => a.Address);`. In my repository I make this call:

```
    public async Task<Apartment> GetByAddressAsync(Address address)
    {
        return await _context.Apartments.FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Address.Equals(address));
    }
```

And it produces the exception above. Any ideas? I don't know why it says I have an 'ApartmentId' in my `Address` value object.

Comment: Have a look at the generated table structure, there is an ApartmentId in the Address table. EF needs that field to remember to which Apartment that Address row belongs to

Comment: @SirRufo `Address` is [owned entity type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities) embedded in `Apartment` table, hence there is neither `Address` table nor `AddressId` column.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Exception message of course is ridiculous, and has nothing in common with the actual problem, which is the expression

```
a => a.Address.Equals(address)
```

It is part of a `IQueryable` expression tree, hence EF Core is trying to *translate* it to SQL.

Object-oriented features like encapsulation don't play well with expression translation, which is based on visibility and knowledge. EF Core is not a decompiler, it cannot see the implementation of your `Equals` method. What usually they do with unknown methods is to throw runtime exception requesting you to either use translatable construct or explicitly switching to client evaluation.

However entity types have special treatment. EF Core is trying to support equality comparisons (`==`, '!=`,`Equals`) translation by implicitly converting it to PK (primary key) comparison.

And here comes the issue with your owned entity type. Note that owned entity types are still *entity* types, but reference owned types like your `Address` have no own PK, hence the exception.

Of course what they do is a bug, but even they "fix" it, the fix would be just different runtime exception.

The solution is of course to not use the `Equals` method, but explicit member comparison, e.g.

```
a => a.Address.StreetNumber.ToUpper() == address.StreetNumber.ToUpper()
    && a.Address.StreetName.ToUpper() == address.StreetName.ToUpper()
    && a.Address.City.ToUpper() == address.City.ToUpper()
    && a.Address.State.ToUpper() == address.State.ToUpper()
    && a.Address.ZipCode.ToUpper() == address.ZipCode.ToUpper()
```

Note that string comparison is controlled by the database, so explicit `ToUpper()` is needed if you need to enforce case insensitive comparison.

Now I know this is a code duplication and breaks encapsulation, but this is the only way (except if you utilize some 3rd party library like [Lambda injection](https://github.com/axelheer/nein-linq/#lambda-injection) by [NeinLinq.EntityFrameworkCore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/#neinlinqentityframeworkcore), [DelegateDecompiler](https://github.com/hazzik/DelegateDecompiler) etc.) to get server side filtering.

Because client side filtering after reading the whole table like

```
_context.Apartments.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Address.Equals(address))
```

would be a performance killer (and is the reason for removing implicit client evaluation in EF Core 3.0+), not to count the lack of natural `async` support (requires additional package, which in turn causes issues with EF Core `DbSet`s - see [Converting EF Core queries from 2.2 to 3.0 - async await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58916542/converting-ef-core-queries-from-2-2-to-3-0-async-await/58920736#58920736)).