# EF Core: No backing field could be found for property of entity type and the property does not have a getter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I`m gettng the following error in EF Core: No backing field could be found for property 'ParentId' of entity type 'Child' and the property does not have a getter.

This is my configuration for the Child entity:

```
            // create shadow property for Parent
            builder.Property<int>("ParentId").IsRequired();

            // make shadow property and foreign key the PK as well
            // i know this may not make the most sense here 
            // in this scenario but it's what I want to do.
            builder.HasKey("ParentId");

            // configure FK
            builder.HasOne(o => o.Parent)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey<Child>("ParentId");
```

And my entities:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Child 
{
    public Parent Parent { get; private set; }

    public void SetParent(Parent p) => Parent = p;
}
```

The error occurs when I call dbContext.Children.Contains(myChild):

```
var child = new Child();
child.Parent = new Parent();

dbContext.Children.Add(child);
dbContext.SaveChanges();

// works fine
Assert.True(dbContext.Children.Any());

// throws InvalidOperationException
Assert.True(dbContext.Children.Contains(myChild)):
```

If I add the shadow property as a real property to the model as such:

```
public class Child 
{
    public int ParentId { get; set;} 

    public Parent Parent { get; private set; }

    public void SetParent(Parent p) => Parent = p;
}
```

then everything works. But I'd like to keep it a shadow property if possible.

Answer (score 4):

**Update:**

Just checked the EF Core 3.1.7 released 3 days ago, and the exception is gone, which means it has been reported/identified and fixed. Hence you can simply upgrade to that version.

**Original:**

The configuration of the shadow property is fine. Unfortunately you are hitting one of the EF Core 3.x bugs.

In order to translate `Contains` method to SQL, EF Core has to convert it to PK equality comparison, something like (in pseudo code)

```
dbContext.Children.Any(c => PK(c) == PK(myChild))
```

which can be seen from the exception stack trace, and apparently is failing to do so when the PK is shadow property.

I've checked the latest at this time EF 5 preview and it appears to be fixed (the issue is gone). So until it gets released, the workaround is to replace implicit entity equalty comparisons (e.g. `Contains(entity)`, `Equals(entity)`, `== entity` etc.) with the corresponding explicit PK comparisons.

In this case, instead of

```
dbContext.Children.Contains(child)
```

you can use either

```
dbContext.Children.Any(c => c.Parent.Id == child.Parent.Id)
```

(worse SQL translation due to another v3.x defect)

or

```
dbContext.Children.Any(c => EF.Property<int>(c, "ParentId") == child.Parent.Id)
```

(proper SQL translation as in v5.0, but uses "magic" strings and requires explicitly specifying the shadow property name and type)

Comment: I deeply admire your courage to enter this minefield time and again.

Comment: Thanks I'm glad to know it's a bug and not something wrong I was doing!

Comment: For others stumbling and coming here, this post helps as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61691178/no-backing-field-could-be-found-for-property-of-entity-type-and-the-property-doe

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Child 
{
    public int ParentId{get;set;}
    public Parent Parent { get; private set; }

    public void SetParent(Parent p) => Parent = p;
}
```

you should define your foreign key variable and remember that private set doesn't create relationship in db

Comment: Sorry but could you explain a bit more? I see you added the last part of my question as the answer but as I said, this is what I'm trying to avoid. My configuration specifies the foreign key (see first snippet of question)

Comment: I want the navigation property to be used, and according to the MS docs, it is possible.